# SLURM - DB and MaxArray MaxJob

Tags: arrays, slurm

I changed the SLURM array configuration in

```
MaxArraySize=100001
MaxJobCount=1000000
```

but can SLURM (db RAM ???) manage all those jobs/arrays, I mean, should I change any other thing in the conf file and what option with what value?

Thanks a lot